# How to navigate from detail page of (Master detail setup) with a button click to Page View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

[click to check the image that makes clear what i am asking >>>>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AViLk.png)

Hi Guys, I am new to programming. I have successfully built a Master Detail app and the Page View Controller is also working but now i want that i can navigate from my detail view with a a button click to Page View Controller. I tried it but its always getting a error as mentioned below:

```
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate 0x604000278140> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.'*
```

I searched a lot everywhere but not found a solution to this. I hope any one of you can help me in that. Please check the image link above to see my page structure in my storyboard. Thanks in advance.

```
**In the Image i have used some short cut words mentioned below:
MVC = MasterViewController,
NC = NavigationController,
tb V = TableView,
PVC = PageViewController**
```

here is the func of button click that i am using to navigate from detail page to Page view controller. PageVC is storyboardID of Page view controller:

```
 @IBAction func goToSlider(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextViewcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageVC") as! PageViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewcontroller, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I believe you have the Page View Controller's name improperly listed in your segue call. Your PVC should have a class name, maybe a custom class name, and the segue when it is called needs to target the exact class name of your PVC

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that is supposed to segue to the PVC?

Comment: I think in PVC controller you forget to connect `IBOutlet` `containerView`

Comment: @kamran, honestly saying i am beginner to ios programming. I don't know how to connect IBOutlet containerView in my PVC. I will be much thankful if you give a bit more detail please.

Comment: @loopstack No problem at all. You can read here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1. Also you can find good tutorials on `Youtube`

Comment: @kamran, thank you for that link. I will check there for the solution of my problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I figured out my problem . The problem was a label in the first view controller of page view controller.